# Insert a Jquery variable number inside Google Chart Array

Tags: jquery

I'm learning to use Google Charts and trying to add a Jquery variable (which contain a number value from an input field) into the Chart array but it only shows the variable name instead of the actual number.

What displays at the moment (when I run this code) is the variable name instead of the number.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
I simply need the variable `test` to be display as Pepper's value

```
test = $('#test_ex').val();


google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([(
    ['Pepper', test ]),
    ['Mushrooms', 30]

  ]);
  
  var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                 'width':400,
                 'height':300};

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I'm sure I'm overthinking this.... Appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: console.log to your test variable and see what is getting printed.

Comment: Hey. thanks for your response. I tried console.log but it prints 'console.log(test)'. I found the solution though... Will post it shortly. Finding Google Chart to be very fiddly

Comment: no worries, happy that you found solution.